# Импорт данных из Excel в БД

Tags: delphi, excel

Существует документ Excel - он может быть разным (может иметь много столбцов, в заголовке может быть шапка, может быть большой диапазон данных). Есть необходимость импорта определенного диапазона данных из Excel в таблицу БД.
Вопрос:

1. Каким образом можно импортировать данные из таблицы Excel в таблицу БД?
2. Можно ли использовать функции Drag&Drop? Скопировать диапазон в Excel и вставить в таблицу (для отображения данных использую компонент DBGrid)?

P.S. СУБД MS SQL, клиент Delphi XE3, для связи с Excel использую компонент ExcelApplication.

Пробовал вот так, но пока сплошные ошибки:

```
procedure TForm4.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ExcelApp: OleVariant;
  i: integer;
begin
  OpenDialog1.Filter := ' ниги Excel |*.xls;*.xslx';
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
    exit;

  try
    ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application'); // открываем объект Excel     
  except
    ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application')
  end;
  ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenDialog1.FileName);
  for i := 1 to ExcelApp.Worksheets.count do
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.add(ExcelApp.Worksheets[i].Name); // выводим в ComboBox1 список листов файла
    Edit1.Text := OpenDialog1.FileName; // выводим полный путь до файла     
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ex_WBook, Ex_WSheet: OleVariant;
  i, list: integer;
  fio, kind, date_birth, position, sector, d1, d2: string;
begin
  list := ComboBox1.ItemIndex; // присваиваем листу номер   
  list := list + 1;

  fio := ComboBox2.Text; // узнаем из какой ячейки (А..Z) забирать данные о фамилиях
  kind := ComboBox3.Text; // узнаем из какой ячейки (А..Z) забирать данные о поле
  date_birth := ComboBox4.Text; // узнаем из какой ячейки (А..Z) забирать данные о дате рождения
  position := ComboBox5.Text; // узнаем из какой ячейки (А..Z) забирать данные о должности
  sector := ComboBox6.Text; // узнаем из какой ячейки (А..Z) забирать данные об отделе
  d1:= SpinEdit1.Text; // получаем начальное значение диапазона данных
  d2:= SpinEdit2.Text; // получаем конечное значение диапазона данных

  ExcelApplication1.Connect; // связываемся с книгой Excel
  Ex_WBook := ExcelApplication1.Workbooks.Open(Edit1.Text, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, 0);
  Ex_WSheet := Ex_WBook.Worksheets[list]; // переходим на выбранный лист книги Excel

  DM.ADOQuery1.Active := true; // открываем набор данных
  DM.ADOQuery1.Insert;
  DM.ADOQuery1.Fields[1].Value := Ex_WSheet.Range
    [fio + d1 + ':' + fio + d2].Value2; // вставляем в поле ФИО данные
  DM.ADOQuery1.Fields[4].Value := Ex_WSheet.Range
    [kind + d1 + ':' + kind + d2].Value2; // вставляем в поле пол данные
  DM.ADOQuery1.Fields[5].Value := Ex_WSheet.Range
    [date_birth + d1 + ':' + date_birth + d2].Value2; // вставляем в поле дата рождения данные
  DM.ADOQuery1.Fields[6].Value := Ex_WSheet.Range
    [position + d1 + ':' + position + d2].Value2; // вставляем в поле должность данные
  DM.ADOQuery1.Fields[7].Value := Ex_WSheet.Range
    [sector + d1 + ':' + sector + d2].Value2;  // вставляем в поле отдел данные

  DM.ADOQuery1.Post;  // обрабатываем запрос
  DM.ADOQuery1.Active := False; // закрываем набор данных
  ExcelApplication1.Quit; // отключаемся от Excel файла
  ExcelApplication1.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ch: char;
begin
  for ch := 'A' to 'Z' do
  begin
    ComboBox2.Items.add(ch); // заполняем ячейки ComboBox символами от A до Z
    ComboBox3.Items.add(ch);
    ComboBox4.Items.add(ch);
    ComboBox5.Items.add(ch);
    ComboBox6.Items.add(ch);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: может будет проще стандартными средствами эксель вытащить данные в текстовый файл с разделителями данных в строках , потом прочитать документ построчно , обработать строку по разделителям сплитом и забрать данные в базу ?

Comment: @Eikhner sqlserver имеет штатные инструменты импорта из экселя, не надо там никаких текстовых файлов, разделителей и т.п.

Comment: Таки где эти ваши ошибки?

Comment: Ошибка Could not convert variant of type (Array variant) into type (OleStr)

Comment: На строке: DM.ADOQuery1.Fields[4].Value := Ex_WSheet.Range
    [kind + d1 + ':' + kind + d2].Value2;

Comment: А предыдущая строчка с ФИО без ошибок проходит?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, потому что данные не добавляются

Comment: Они и не добавятся, пока вы не сделаете `Post`, а вы до него не доходите. Текст ошибки вам явно сообщает о том, что свойство `Value2` имеет тип `Array variant` (массив), а `ADOQuery1.Fields[i].Value` типа `OleStr` (строка), и система не знает как массив преобразовать в строку.